# "Chart isn't Declared error" My Code works perfectly in Codepen, however when running locally I keep getting an error

Tags: javascript, html

My code works perfectly in Codepen, but once I started working with it locally I keep getting a "Chart isn't declared error". Not sure if its my HTML structure or Javascript. Codepen JS doesn't appear to show signs of a problem.

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("barChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'dodgerblue';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;

var data = {
labels: ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry","Carmel", "Tripple 
Chocolate"],
  datasets: [
    {
        label: "Ice Cream Sales ",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: [
            'moccasin',
            'saddlebrown',
            'lightpink',
            'gold',
            'saddlebrown'],
        data: [15, 14, 10, 6, 2]
    }
 ]
};

var options = {
    title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Items Sold',
              position: 'bottom'
          },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
};
 var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'bar',
 data: data,
 options: options
 });
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="graph1.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <script src="graph1.js"></script>
   </body>

   </html>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/ksav22/pen/dLmdqM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in codepen, you have this script attached ("Open JS Settings" modal):

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js
```

Without it, `Chart` *is* undefined.

You need to link to it in your HTML (and before your own script using Chart).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to wait until all the files are loaded before executing your JS code. All of your procedural code should be in the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});` anonymous function. Otherwise, if your script is loaded before chart.js is loaded, it will say that "chart is undefined" because it hasn't been loaded yet!

Your user-defined functions and global variable declarations should be outside of the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});` function, however.